# 15.10 CUPS server error

Tags: 15.10, printing

Getting the following error message after install my printer:

```
"CUPS server error
There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'Transport endpoint is not connected'."

Cancel / Retry
```

On either option, I get the next error message:

```
"Raw Queue
Unable to get queue details. Treating queue as raw."

Ok
```

The printer properties screen opens up.....what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Start at `http://localhost:631`, login with your userid/password.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks. I figured it out.  Missed a checkbox on the sharing setup menu.